# How does awk process an input file?

Tags: awk

I am wondering how the "internals" of awk work.

When awk runs, does it load the input file completely in memory or does it read the file chunk by chunk?

Comment: chunk by RS-terminated chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking of files, specifically, `awk` will first read your program, interpret it and then apply it to each line of the file, one by one - actually, this is strictly true only if the RS is the default one. Multiline parsing requires going more in-depth. Please see below (italics mine):

> ### 1.4 An Example with Two Rules
>
> *The awk utility reads the input files one line at a time*. For each line, awk tries the patterns of each
> rule. If several patterns match, then several actions execute in the
> order in which they appear in the awk program. If no patterns match,
> then no actions run.
>
> *After processing all the rules that match the line* (and perhaps there
> are none), *awk reads the next line*. [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getting-Started)

Also see

> ### 7.4.8 The next Statement
>
> [...]
>
> At the highest level, *awk program execution is a loop that reads an*
> *input record and then tests each rule’s pattern against it*. If you
> think of this loop as a for statement whose body contains the rules,
> then the next statement is analogous to a continue statement. It skips
> to the end of the body of this implicit loop and executes the
> increment (which reads another record). [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Next-Statement)

But what if a Record Separator is used to span more lines?

> ### 4.1 How Input Is Split into Records
>
> *awk divides the input for your program into records and fields*. It
> keeps track of the number of records that *have been read so far* from
> the current input file. This value is stored in a predefined variable
> called FNR, which is reset to zero every time a new file is started. [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records)

Since we discovered that `awk` reads the file one line (actually, one record) at the time, let's have a look at the `getline()` function:

> The getline command returns 1 if it finds a record and 0 if it
> encounters the end of the file. If there is some error in getting a
> record, such as a file that cannot be opened, then getline returns -1.
> In this case, gawk sets the variable ERRNO to a string describing the
> error that occurred. [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline)

The instruction is interpreted and executed by the interpreter, which attempts to read new content from the file. Since *this* is a function, it returns accordingly to the findings: awk might not be able to access the input file anymore, resulting in a `-1` and `ERRNO`.

Comment: awk starts reading your input and parses it against the RS. Once a RS is read (or EOF), the interpreted program is executed against that record. Once that is done (or a `next` or `getline` call is made), the input is sampled again until a new RS or EOF

Comment: @edmorton I'm aware of that, my comment was from before anything other than lines was mentioned. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

the advantage of the regex based field and record separators (what many think of as just columns and rows), is that merely by setting

RS = "^$"

you can read it the whole file one shot. Once i was abusing mawk2 to its limit, flattening a 12 million row, 3 column thing that's 900MB of text filled with Unicode, force loading it as one-line (by setting FS = "[=\n]" )* .....

it's fun watching it not break a sweat, and come back with NF above 36 million. =p

- i'm super lazy so i just found an easily typable character least appearing in song and artist names requiring no escaping in any scenario, and poses zero danger when unquoted at the terminal and went with it. I'd scream if i have to deal with FPAT.

So i chose the equal sign, and using brute force and re-casting any existing equal signs in song names out to its unicode double-width cousin.

This way it also helps avoid having to quote strings in any of the text files when in storage.